# Kotlin coroutines and Java Completable future integration

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Usually I'm using standard [kotlin-jdk8](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) library to jump from Java `*future` API world into the Kotlin's `suspend` heaven.

And it worked great for me, until I encountered Neo4J cursor API, where I can't do `.await()` on the completion stage, because it immediately starts fetching millions of records into memory.

Kotlin way does not work for me, like this:

```
suspend fun query() {
    driver.session().use { session ->

        val cursor: StatementResultCursor = session.readTransactionAsync {
            it.runAsync("query ...", params)
        }.await() // HERE WE DIE WITH OOM

        var record = cursor.nextAsync().await()

        while (record != null) {
            val node = record.get("node")
            mySuspendProcessingFunction(node)
            record = cursor.nextAsync().await()
        }
    }
}
```

At the same time, Java API works good, we fetch records one by one:

```
suspend fun query() {
    session.readTransactionAsync { transaction ->
        transaction.runAsync("query ...", params).thenCompose { cursor ->
            cursor.forEachAsync { record ->
                runBlocking { // BUT I NEED TO DO RUN BLOCKING HERE :(
                    val node = record.get("node")
                    mySuspendProcessingFunction(node)
                }
            }
        }
    }.thenCompose {
        session.closeAsync()
    }.await()
}
```

The second option works for me, but it is pretty ugly - definitely not Kotlin way, and what is more important, I need to use runBlocking (but these whole block is executed within suspend function)

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

UPD
Tried to do this exercise using new Flow() feature, unfortunately results are the same:

```
suspend fun query() {
    session.readTransactionAsync { transaction ->
        transaction.runAsync(query, params).thenApply { cursor ->
            cursor.asFlow().onEach { record ->
                val node = record.get("node")
                mySuspendProcessingFunction(node)
            }
        }
    }.thenCompose {
        session.closeAsync()
    }.await()
}
fun StatementResultCursor.asFlow() = flow {
    do {
        val record = nextAsync().await()
        if (record != null) emit(record)
    } while (record != null)
}
```